# Issue with reading gradle command line params in karate-config.js

Tags: karate

I am trying to pass some cmd line args from gradle to be used in karate-config.js.
Cmd: `./gradlew test -Denv=qa -Dmodule=payments`

I looked at https://github.com/intuit/karate#command-line and followed similar steps and put this in build.gradle:

```
test {
     ...
    systemProperty "karate.env", System.properties.getProperty("env")
    systemProperty "karate.module", System.properties.getProperty("module")
}
```

Now in karate-config.js, I have code like below:

```
var environmentvar = karate.env;
var modulevar = karate.module;
```

environment var (`karate.env`) variable gets the correct value, but module var (`karate.module`) always shows as undefined. Any pointers on how to fix this?

Karate 0.9.4
JDK 1.8.0_231

Answer (score 1):

Aren't you missing a `karate.` for e.g.:

```
System.properties.getProperty("karate.env")
```

Comment: That's not the reason. `-Denv` goes in and is mappend in `test` task to `karate.env`.

Comment: @Peter ah okay. I'm not a gradle expert, so all yours :P

Comment: Yes, System.properties.getProperty("karate.env") does not work. Only using System.properties.getProperty("env") works. 

And System.properties.getProperty("karate.module") or System.properties.getProperty("module") does not work. So wanted to know if there is any other way to pass.

Comment: @Peter may have other suggestions, but mine is to follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue or switch to maven

Answer (score 1):

Just didn't regcognized the important information that accessing `karate.env` works.

The environment variable `karate.env` is treated special. Using `karate` object to access other system properties the same way does not work.

You should read [accessing system properties](https://github.com/intuit/karate#karate-properties).

Solution: Use `karate.properties['prop.name']` to access your module system variable.

In your case:

```
var environmentvar = karate.env;
var modulevar = karate.properties['module'];
```